# mysql connection to database error

Tags: centos, mysql

Two weeks ago I bought new server, and since then sometimes I have  error in connection to database on this server. This are error logs after restartng mysqld

var/log/mysqld.log:

```
131206 10:54:37 [ERROR] Error in accept: Too many open files
131206 10:58:53 [ERROR] Error in accept: Too many open files
131206 11:03:09 [ERROR] Error in accept: Too many open files
131206 11:07:25 [ERROR] Error in accept: Too many open files
131206 11:11:41 [ERROR] Error in accept: Too many open files
131206 11:15:58 [ERROR] Error in accept: Too many open files
131206 11:20:14 [ERROR] Error in accept: Too many open files
131206 11:24:30 [ERROR] Error in accept: Too many open files
131206 11:28:46 [ERROR] Error in accept: Too many open files
131206 11:33:02 [ERROR] Error in accept: Too many open files
```

What can I do for solving this problem?

Sorry for bad english.

UPDATE:

can you help me update my.cnf?

```
[mysqld]
local-infile=0
innodb_file_per_table
[mysqld_safe]
log-error=/var/log/mysqld.log
pid-file=/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid

Linux server.com 2.6.32-279.el6.x86_64 #1 SMP Fri Jun 22 12:19:21 UTC 2012 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux


PHP 5.3.27 (cli) (built: Nov 28 2013 02:21:29)
Copyright (c) 1997-2013 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v2.3.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2013 Zend Technologies
    with the ionCube PHP Loader v4.4.4, Copyright (c) 2002-2013, by ionCube Ltd., and
    with Zend Guard Loader v3.3, Copyright (c) 1998-2010, by Zend Technologies

mysql  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.5.31, for Linux (x86_64) using readline 5.1

CentOS release 6.4 (Final)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your last update indicates that you have problem with to many opened files. You must increase ulimit for number of maximum opened files.

Default I think is 1024 (You can check it by execute `ulimit -a`). Increase this value by execute

```
ulimit -n newvaule
```

This set it to a new value for this running session, which takes effect immediately

Alternatively, if you want the changes to survive reboot, do the following:
As root, edit the file /etc/security/limits.conf and add these two lines toward the end:

```
* soft nofile 16000
* hard nofile 20000
```

The two lines above change the max number of file handles - nofile - to new settings.